# R: Failing to knit on a pivot longer, despite the function working when run by itself

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

Kia Ora,

I am running into an issue where I have a pivot_longer() than works when I run the code and the output works and is correct. However, when I try to knitt to html I get the following error message:

```
Error in -`x type` : invalid argument to unary operator Calls: <Anonymous> ... lapply -> FUN -> reorder -> reorder.default -> tapply Execution halted
```

This is an example of the offending code:

```
longer_df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(contains("common_phrase")),
               names_to = "x type",
               values_to = "x quantity")
```

Does anyone have an idea why the code works, but fails to knitt?

Comment: if remove space of names_to and values_to, does knit run? (e.g., x_type)

Comment: It still fails to knit, albeit a slightly different error message : Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object `x quantity` not found Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> f ->scales_add_defaults -> lapply -> FUN Execution halted

Comment: is `df` defined in the Notebook? What happens if you `rm(df)` and re-run all chuncks?

Comment: @Waldi df is defined in the code chunks before the one that is an issue. I tried rm(df) both in the set up chunk and in the chunk that is failing. In the first case it failed because it was not defined, in the second the same issue as above resulted.

Comment: @cuttlefish44 I replied earlier but forgot to tag you

Comment: Hmm, excuse me I couldn't help you because I can't reproduce your problem...

Answer (score 0):

It appears I fixed the issue by adding 'na.rm = TRUE' to my ggplot calls. Weird given that the errors were not attributed to a ggplot call.